# Indent or Pad Table Column Content

Tags: css, padding

I am looking to indent content of table columns BUT NOT the content of the table heading row. I had found some code on another thread that solved the issue of needing to pad only certain columns, but this also pads the table heading row.

```
/* first column */
td:first-child {
padding-left: 20px;  
}

/* second column */ 
td:first-child + td {
padding-left: 10px;  
}

/* third columns */ {
td:first-child + td + td {
padding-left: 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TH tag instead of a TD tag for your header row in your HTML.

Comment: Tried that, but then I lose all my custom formatting in the table head row - unless I am missing something else - I tried to use a class for the tablehead row to retain its formatting but can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: Do the custom formatting for the th tag in the same way that you would for the td tag: th:first-child { css goes here }